# Unable to execute docker commands inside jenkins container(docker command not found)

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running a jenkins container on an EC2 instance and executing a simple pipeline to test and deploy a simple flask application.I am using my git repo which has the Jenkinsfile.
Using the pipeline I am building and testing inside a temporary container and then want to deploy it as a container app.
Here is the Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      filename "Dockerfile"
      args '-i --entrypoint='
               }
        }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        echo 'hello world'
      }
    }
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        sh 'python3 test.py'
      }
      post {
        always {
          junit 'test-results/*.xml'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh 'echo $PATH'
        sh 'whoami'
      }
    }
 }
```

I am trying to execute docker commands using 'sh' but the jenkins build log says command not found which is weird as i have confirmed that docker is installed in jenkins container by using
`sudo docker exec -it jenkins /bin/sh`
and then
`which docker`
the outputs '/usr/bin/docker'

After some investigation it looks like the 'sh' commands are executed inside the container as the $PATH values are different from jenkins container in build log.
Here is the build log from the above Jenkinsfile.

```
Started by user admin
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/thelogical/webmf-python-flask.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/thelogical/webmf-python-flask.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/thelogical/webmf-python-flask.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/thelogical/webmf-python-flask.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision ac14a74f94e23fb5b1cd4434ded9d464e4e22022 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f ac14a74f94e23fb5b1cd4434ded9d464e4e22022 # timeout=10
Commit message: "ok"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 7d4f2857afa84e54d77ef4fea0aad0b7404f2415 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup)
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t 4f900583e018f99394f091d4af5db99e6cc803bf -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  102.4kB

Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.7.6
 ---> f66befd33669
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d9df4960eb00
Step 3/7 : ADD . /usr/src/app
 ---> 4769ae8f0fee
Step 4/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in aefd5251b16a
Collecting Click==7.0
  Downloading Click-7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (81 kB)
Collecting Flask==1.1.1
  Downloading Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
  Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==2.11.1
  Downloading Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug==1.0.0
  Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Collecting xmlrunner==1.7.7
  Downloading xmlrunner-1.7.7.tar.gz (5.6 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: xmlrunner
  Building wheel for xmlrunner (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for xmlrunner (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for xmlrunner: filename=xmlrunner-1.7.7-py3-none-any.whl size=6235 sha256=de9fcea7814bfad46e0cdb3e3bcfd2d7ef139e8b9e3eb781f5af15742146e748
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/bb/ae/64/7394a8365bd8e7bf4c49b01d80c0260d1c1ec975183ac1ce37
Successfully built xmlrunner
Installing collected packages: Click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, Flask, xmlrunner
Successfully installed Click-7.0 Flask-1.1.1 Jinja2-2.11.1 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.0 itsdangerous-1.1.0 xmlrunner-1.7.7
[91mWARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[0mRemoving intermediate container aefd5251b16a
 ---> 9585ddbee5b7
Step 5/7 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Running in 856b365825b8
Removing intermediate container 856b365825b8
 ---> 7b1860335847
Step 6/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
 ---> Running in d4a68d6de72b
Removing intermediate container d4a68d6de72b
 ---> 7c83dea48a62
Step 7/7 : CMD ["app.py"]
 ---> Running in 536cf8410f05
Removing intermediate container 536cf8410f05
 ---> 90461bad0db4
Successfully built 90461bad0db4
Successfully tagged 4f900583e018f99394f091d4af5db99e6cc803bf:latest
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . 4f900583e018f99394f091d4af5db99e6cc803bf
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins seems to be running inside container 13258ed4dd2e1941f9e4867fb4872025bd5d3250b7188bb2d448aab62b145342
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -i --entrypoint= -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test --volumes-from 13258ed4dd2e1941f9e4867fb4872025bd5d3250b7188bb2d448aab62b145342 -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** 4f900583e018f99394f091d4af5db99e6cc803bf cat
$ docker top 85265dd4a4b76f7b8f57475428fb10eacc131ebe3b2a416444d31c81e8fd3612 -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] echo
hello world
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] sh
+ python3 test.py

Running tests...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.009s

OK

Generating XML reports...
Post stage
[Pipeline] junit
Recording test results
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[Pipeline] sh
+ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1000
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 85265dd4a4b76f7b8f57475428fb10eacc131ebe3b2a416444d31c81e8fd3612
$ docker rm -f 85265dd4a4b76f7b8f57475428fb10eacc131ebe3b2a416444d31c81e8fd3612
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

BOTTOMLINE: I want to deploy the flask container after successful testing but i am not sure how to do it. I tried executing 'docker' but it fails by saying 'command not found'.

Here are the contents of the Dockerfile if needed.

```
FROM python:3.7.6

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

In jenkins container the $PATH is
`/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: The actual error is the `whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1000`; this causes the `whoami` process to exit with a failing status code (1), and everything after this is teardown.  That's not actually a surprising error in this context.

Comment: (You might find it a little more straightforward to combine `CMD ["python", "app.py"]`: the `ENTRYPOINT` line forces Docker to interpret any command you type as a Python script name, which leads to weird workarounds like the blank `--entrypoint=` option.)

Comment: @DavidMaze yes i tried that as well but with no luck. I think the issue is that all the shell commands specified by 'sh' in Jenkinsfile are executed inside flask container rather than the jenkins container which has docker installed. The 'whoami' output confirms it as the output should be 'jenkins' user.

Comment: Yes, I would expect that `agent` block instructs Jenkins to tell all of those stages to run in a Docker container as described by that `Dockerfile`.